# Is there a way to easily print the pages from an ASP.NET site?

Tags: asp.net, printing

My PM just stopped by and he wanted a copy of all of our pages... Is there a way to do this for all pages without having to go to each one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Free/Open Source application to crawl you're own site:

> http://www.httrack.com/

Then send the resulting local html files to the printer.

---

Should mention that httrack has [a configuration for controlling how deep](http://www.httrack.com/html/step9_opt2.html) you traverse you're site hierarchy (and other options).

Answer (score 1):

This is a really crazy idea but how about this:

Get a list of all the pages in an array and use JavaScript to load each page with an interval of like 20 seconds. When the page gets loaded fire the window.print() Javascript function. The print job will be finished within 20 seconds and the new page gets loaded and the same thing will again happen.

Comment: I believe that window.print though will show the print dialog.